# randomizing colors for a jqPlot Graph

Tags: jquery-mobile, jqplot

Currently I'm setting particular colors for my jqPlot graph using `seriesColors: [ "#55A9D3", "#D4EDE2", "#EA2E49"]`, however I would like jqPlot to simply randomize colors for me if the graph ends up having more than just 3 results (the graph is being generated on dynamic data). Is there a way to do this? Thank so much!

Comment: When you say random, how random?  Pretty easy to come up with random RGB values, but some of them will be quite ugly on a plot.  Why not use jqplots default built-in colors?

Comment: @Mark can I use jqplots default built-in colors starting after these three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
seriesColors: $.merge([ "#55A9D3", "#D4EDE2", "#EA2E49"], $.jqplot.config.defaultColors)
```

Comment: Hey is there any way of changing this default color pallete to make it looker better? It's just really green and orangy and bad as is? Thanks

Comment: Look into the theme engine. I've never really played with it, though:  http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-themeEngine-js.html

Comment: Suppose if my seriesColors array is as follows. seriesColors: [ "#55A9D3", "#D4EDE2", "#EA2E49"]. And if there are more than 3 values in the Series, then the colors should repeat(as said in the documentation). But it doesn't. It just shows the rest of the slices in 'black' color. Any idea, how I can fix this.